# gcc static library compilation

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

i have made a static library using the ar command after an object creation using gcc -o file.o -c file.c.

Now i'm trying to use the gcc to link this library in the compilation with a command similar to this

```
gcc -I /PathInclude -L /PathStaticLib -lm \
  -std=c99 -o file file.o -lstatic_library_name
```

with static_library_name i mean that the file is named

```
libstatic_library_name.a
```

Since the files structure is quite complex (because basically in the compiling i also substitute some macro definition etc) i don't post all the code, do you have any thought on what is going on? if not what kind of info could i provide to you in order to help me?

PS. there aren't a lot o files, but the internal structure is a bit complicated to explain in few words, so... let me know what do you need.

I can give you the make file content if you need, is not complicated.

PS. The command is...

```
gcc -I../CModels -L../CModels/ -std=c99 -o ref_approx_bs3_log2_4_4_1ulp_arch1 
 ref_approx_bs3_log2_4_4_1ulp_arch1.o -lm -lmy_float
```

The error is

```
ref_approx_bs3_log2_4_4_1ulp_arch1.o: In function `cogen_fp_bs3_log2_4_4_1ulp_arch1':
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x2229): undefined reference to `cast'
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x22d0): undefined reference to `cast'
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x22f7): undefined reference to `cast'
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x232e): undefined reference to `sumFP'
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x2350): undefined reference to `diffFP'
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x2375): undefined reference to `mulFP'
ref_approx_log2.c:(.text+0x239c): undefined reference to `sumFP'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using

```
nm my_float.a
```

the output is

```
my_float.o:
0000000000000ca8 T _Z11castToFixedyPyyyy
0000000000000a0c T _Z12splitIntFracyPyS_yy
0000000000000324 T _Z28rightShift_and_round2NearestyyPyyy
000000000000005c T _Z3ldzy
0000000000000132 T _Z3mulyyy
000000000000048a T _Z4castyPyyyyy
0000000000000000 T _Z4maxuyy
000000000000002e T _Z4minuyy
00000000000014dc T _Z5mulFPyyPyyy
0000000000000cc2 T _Z5sumFPyyPyyy
000000000000147a T _Z6diffFPyyPyyy
0000000000000300 T _Z9ldzFormatyy
                 U __gxx_personality_v0
```

So i guess the library .a is ok...

Comment: I don't see a problem or question here.

Comment: I'm sorry... the problem basically is that even if i include the static library i've created, the compiler spit out the classic error "undefined reference". But i don't understand the why... that's the problem.

Comment: Please update your question to include (a) the actual command line you're using to build things and (b) the actual text of the error message.  This will allow us to ask more useful questions.

Comment: I've tried with the -E to see the macro substitution, basically the substitution happens... how do i use the option you mentioned?

Comment: Using nm honestly i don't know how to read the output... what should i look for?

Comment: Any chance the problem is in the makefile?

Comment: Anyway i don't understand those prefix _Z11 and so on... because the symbol expected from the file that should include "my_float.h" expect the name reported in the error...

Answer (score 0):

As per the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options), AFAIR, there should be no *space* in between `-L` or `-I` and the `path`. Change your command to

```
 .. -I/PathInclude -L/PathStaticLib ...
```

Comment: also, why `-lm` resides before the object file? Move that to the last.

Comment: @Lukkio also, are you sure `my_float` library is fine?

Comment: I think so... i've updated with nm option but i don't see error

Answer (score 0):

Error says that the references to cast, sumFP, diffFP , mulFP are not defined. Need to make sure that they are defined in the library.